# Invalid argument supplied for foreach in LARAVEL

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

When contacts doesnt contain anything it gives the invalid arg error for foreach.
What is the best way to handle it here? I'm new to php, any suggestions would be great.
I understand that if the `$contacts` is empty thats why its doing that error.

What this code does is it gets all the list of my contacts.
Then it creates a query that gets all users that IS NOT my contact.
But if a user doesn't have any contact then that means the $contacts would be empty.
Now I get the error. How to handle it?

```
$me = User::loggedin();
//get all my contacts
$contacts = DB::table('contacts')
                ->where('status', 'contact')
        ->where('uid_by', $me)
        ->orWhere('uid_to', $me)
            ->select(
            DB::raw("IF(uid_by = $me, uid_to, uid_by) AS user_id")
        )
        ->get();

if ($contacts == null) {
    $contacts = 0;
}

$users_id = array();

foreach ($contacts as $contact) {
    $users_id[] = $contact->user_id;
}
//add my self to the NOT included list
array_push($users_id, $me);
//query for users that user_id is not me or my list of contacts
$data = DB::table('users')
        ->leftJoin('user_avatars', 'users.uid', '=', 'user_avatars.uid')
        ->leftJoin('files', 'user_avatars.fid', '=', 'files.fid')
        ->whereNotIn('users.uid', $users_id)
        ->where('privacy', 'public')
        ->select('users.uid', 'first_name', 'last_name', DB::raw('IFNULL(files.filename, \'default.jpg\') AS avatar'), 'privacy')
        ->get();

return Response::json(array('non_contacts' => $data));
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't set an empty array to be 0:

```
if ($contacts == null) {
    $contacts = array();
}
```

Really though, I don't see why you need to include this if statement at all: if no rows are are returned, foreach will never loop.

Comment: Oh men. I'm really new. Sorry. And I removed it and it works well now. any other thing you can suggest about the code? Thank you. will accept the answer asap.